# AudioKit - How can I get MIDI inputs to work?

Tags: macos, midi, audiokit

Using AudioKit v5-main. I'm going out of my mind, as I can't seem to get any MIDI inputs to work in my project (MacOS). I simply get no input.

I have run the MIDI Monitor in Cookbook successfully.
I have copied the MIDIMonitor to a new clean project successfully.

To figure out what's wrong, I have copied the MIDIMonitor.swift into my own project, stripped it down so all it runs is the MIDI monitor. No luck.

When I close MIDI Monitor (the one that's embedded in my project) I get the following error, which I don't get when I close the version embedded in CookBook:

MIDI+Receiving.swift:closeInput(uid:):450:Error disconnecting MIDI port: -50 (MIDI+Receiving.swift:closeInput(uid:):450)

MIDI+Receiving.swift:closeInput(uid:):456:Error displosing  MIDI port: -50 (MIDI+Receiving.swift:closeInput(uid:):456)

(B.t.w., there seems to be a typo in MIDI+Receiving.swift, should have been "disposing" and no extra space).

It seems somehow that the MIDI input was never properly initialised, but I get no error when I open the MIDI inputs.

Anyway, anybody has a clue on what could provoke this error?
Project setting?

MacOS 11.2.3
Xcode 12.4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have background modes audio checked as below:

[image: Capabilites Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! I believe that Background Modes relate only to iOS targets (I might be wrong)? Anyway, I have enabled Audio in the App Sandbox section but with no luck.

Comment: Oh yeah, the Cookbook app runs on the Mac through Catalyst. Might worth an experiment to see if you can get your MIDI Monitor working via Catalyst.